# c++ -> template meta programming vs template functions

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

I am learning C++ template meta-programming. I want to know the difference between the following constructs. Suppose the classic example of the factorial.

## Example 1

```
template <int n>
struct factorial
{
  enum { fac = n*factorial<n-1>::fac };
};
factorial<4> ex;
```

(where we omit the termination conditions for brevity.)

## Example 2

```
template<int n> factorial<n> foo1(){return factorial<n>();}
```

## Example 3

```
template<int n> int foo2(){return n*foo2<n-1>();}
template<> int foo2<0>(){return 1;}
int ex2=foo2<4>()
```

## Example 4

```
template<int n>
  int foo3(){
    int k=1;
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++) k*=i;
    return k;
}
int ex3=foo3<4>();
```

What are the differences between the 4 examples? In particular, what is done at compile time for each variant?

## My Thoughts

It's clear that example 1 is completely compile-time. The second, I think, is also compile-time, but I'm not sure what the compiler does. The third is also at compile time? I'm not certain.

The fourth isn't compile-time. What *is* done at compile time? Does the compiler create a code-generator for the function, where n is "replaced" by the constant value?

Please correct me, or add to my thoughts.

Comment: this sounds like you want to use a debugger

Comment: Note that with modern C++ you can do many of the things you'd have used TMP for in the past with `constexpr` and the subset of C++ that's allowed in constexprs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the differences between the 4 examples? In particular, what is done at compile time for each variant?
>
> It's clear that example 1 is completely compile-time.

Quite right: the `factorial<4>` is a type, and a type is created/computed at compile-time. So the factorial of 4 is computed at compile-time. At run-time, the object `ex` of type `factorial<4>` is initialized (can be initialized: the compiler is free do it at compile-time also).

> The second, I think, is also compile-time, but I'm not sure what the compiler does.

I don't see the `ex1` row.

I suppose

```
factorial<4> ex1 = foo1<4>();
```

or, starting from C++11, also

```
auto ex1 = foo1<4>();
```

The answer is quite as for case (1): `foo<N>()` return a `factorial<N>` that is a type and a type is created/computed compile time; so the factorial of N is computed compile time; run time is called (can be called) the function `foo1()` and is initialized (can be initialized) the object `ex1` of type `factorial<4>`.

> The third is also at compile time? I'm not certain.

No: It returns an `int`, not a `factorial<N>`. It's usually computed run-time (even if the compiler is free to compute it at compile-time).

But, starting from C++11, you can write `foo2()` as a `constexpr` function, like so:

```
template<int n>
constexpr int foo2(){return n*foo2<n-1>();}

template<>
constexpr int foo2<0>(){return 1;}
```

A `constexpr` function can be computed compile-time or run-time, but you can force its computation at compile-time if you use it for a value that must be known at compile-time.

By example, initializing a `constexpr` variable:

```
constexpr int ex2 = foo2<4>();  // factorial computed compile time
```

or for a size of a C-style array:

```
int  a[foo2<4>()];  // factorial computed compile time
```

of for a template argument:

```
factorial<foo2()> ex;  // factorial of factorial computed compile time
```

But the `constexpr` function can be simpler and more flexible. You can write it as an untemplated recursive function as follows [**Caution: code not tested**]

```
constexpr int foo2 (int n)
 { return n ? n * foo2(n-1) : 1; }
```

This way `foo2()` can compute (at run-time, obviously) factorial values for run-time variables. For example:

```
for ( auto i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i )
   std::cout << i << "! = " << foo2(i) << std::endl;
```

Observe that `foo2()` remains usable at compile-time, but the value `n` must be known at compile-time.

I mean

```
constexpr int i1 = 4;  // i1 is usable compile time
int i2 = 4;            // i2 isn't usable compile time

int f1 = foo2(4);  // OK: computed run time (f1 isn't constexpr)
int f2 = foo2(i1); // OK: computed run time (f2 isn't constexpr)
int f3 = foo2(i2); // OK: computed run time (+ i2 ins't constexpr)
constexpr f4 = foo2(4);  // OK: computed compile time
constexpr f5 = foo2(i1); // OK: computed compile time
constexpr f6 = foo2(i2); // compilation error! (i2 isn't constexpr)
```

> The fourth isn't compile-time. What is done at compile time? Does the compiler create a code-generator for the function, where n is "replaced" by the constant value?

Right.

But you can define it `constexpr` (starting from C++14: it's too complex to be a C++11 `constexpr` function), so it can be computed at compile-time or run-time and *must* be computed compile-time when the value must be known at compile-time.

```
constexpr int ex3 = foo3<4>(); // factorial computed compile time
```

As `foo2()`, `foo3()` can be defined `constexpr` receiving a not-template parameter (I repeat: starting from C++14) [**Caution: code not tested**]

```
constexpr int foo3 (int n)
{
   int k = 1;
   for (int i=2 ; i <= n ; i++ )
      k *= i;
   return k;
}
```

or, in a more compact way:

```
constexpr int foo3 (int n)
{
   int ret = n ? n : 1;

   while ( --n > 0 )
      ret *= n;

   return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for an in-depth explanation. One more question: It seems, that in template meta-programming, only types are computed at compile time. This is why the third, ex2, is computed at runtime (as it returns an int, not a type). Is this (one of) the correct conclusion(s) to take from your answer?

Comment: @LeastSquaresWonderer - well... yes, template meta-programming is based on template based types computations; in `foo2()` and `foo3()` there isn't need of a computation over a type (you use only `int`) so the compiler is free to create compile time the set of the requested functions and call they (so compute the factorial) run time. With `constexpr` you can write meta-programs that aren't template (but you can also mix `constexpr` function and template meta programming).

Comment: @LeastSquaresWonderer - anyway, can you please add the `ex1` initialization instruction; so I can modify the answer regarding point 2.

Comment: A language-lawyer note: "even in cases where the computation must be done at compile time, the implementation is free to use the result of a runtime calculation rather than preserving the one computed at compile time". Cited [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1535).